# Print text successively Python

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to print a text gradually.

```
import time

print time.sleep(1),'Whats ', time.sleep(1),'your', time.sleep(1),'PROBLEM?'
```

No errors occur. but I do get.

```
None Whats  None your None PROBLEM?
```

Is this possible to achive?
If so any better ways to do it or a solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot print a function such as `time.sleep(1)` because it doesn't return anything, therefore, the None. Instead, try the following:

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

text = "What's your problem?"
text = text.split()

for k in text:
        stdout.write(k+' ')
        stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)

print '\n'
```

**Output:**

```
What's $ your $ problem?
```

The `$` signifies the pause of 1 second. If you use the following code:

```
import time

text = "What's your PROBLEM?"
text = text.split()            #text is a list now: ["What's", "your", "PROBLEM?"]

for i in text:
    print i,
    time.sleep(1)
```

It prints everything at once after 3 seconds.

## Look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nPHw4m7SeE&feature=youtube_gdata_player)

Comment: @user3569323, if it works, remember to click the green tick next to my answer (full disclosure: it gives you +2 reputation :)).

Answer (score 2):

You should put it in a loop:

```
import time

text = "What's your PROBLEM?"
text = text.split()            #text is a list now: ["What's", "your", "PROBLEM?"]

for i in text:
    print i,
    time.sleep(1)

[OUTPUT]
What's (1 sec) your (1 sec) PROBLEM?      #the (1 sec) doesn't actually print
```

Comment: This script will print it on the same line, but will print everything after 3 seconds

Comment: @user3569323, I had just updated my answer. Do `print i,` instead of `print i`

Comment: This code does not work as you said in OUTPUT, it prints everything after 3 seconds

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: @aj8uppal, python-2.7 and judging from the OP's print statement in his question, so is he.

Comment: If I use "print i," it waits the 3 seconds then print the whole text.

Comment: @user3569323, Which python do you have?

Comment: 2.7 if I don't use the "print i," and use the normally i it prints as it's supposed but on the next lines.

Comment: Look at this video: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nPHw4m7SeE&feature=youtube_gdata_player) *Ignore the background noise :)*

Comment: @aj8uppal, I can't believe it. I just ran this on my computer like 10 times and it works perfectly fine. I don't understand. :(

Comment: Did you see the video?

Comment: @aj8uppal, I did. Yes. And then I tried it again. Still works for me. But I guess if your solution works for the OP, that is the way to go..

Comment: That is odd. Do you mind posting a video so I could see your code working?

Comment: @aj8uppal, Sure. What screen-capture software should I use?

Comment: Try using [this](http://camstudio.org/) if you are running Windows, or if you are running Mac, use QuickTime Player

Comment: @aj8uppal, Sorry it took time to upload: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-XcaFTJjk0

Comment: That is actually really odd... :)

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep(1)` returns the null value: `None`. The following code would produce the same output: `print None, 'Whats ', None,'your', None,'PROBLEM?'`. Though it wouldn't pause.

What you want to do here is loop over the different blocks of text text that you want to print and sleep after each printing (just as sshashank124 recommends).

```
import time
words = ["What's", "your", "PROBLEM?"]

for word in words:
  print word,
  time.sleep(1)
```